# I cant keep the text as it is on the screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am beginner and I what add a text that will change if it was seen in a smaller mobile
I pasted here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/aboutus"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the picture, I want it to look like Pic1 and Pic2, the problem is, Im making it like Pic3 and I don't want that!

[image]

Comment: change layout_width to wrap content and check it again

Comment: Try setting the TextView's textSize="64sp"

Answer (score 0):

Please update your xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1d72c3"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".main" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/aboutus"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main problem is your textView's width is `"fill_parent". Your texts fill screen because of that.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a percentage for the text or just number?

Comment: What do you mean with "percentage for the text or just number". You can set textSize with sp. Example android:textSize="16sp"

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative units. I really recommend you to read this:
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
To make a long story short, using "sp" units is the way to go. use the attribute

```
android:textSize="15sp"
```

replacing 15 by the size you think it is the most appropriate for your needs.

Comment: Check the edited answer if you are in a hurry, but please, read the link later!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way you have setup your layout is not the right solution if you wan't to have different layouts for different screens. Your outermost view is a Relative layout with width and height set to fill the screen (that's what fill parent does). Now inside that Relative Layout you have a LinearLayout with width and height set to match its parent (RelativeLayout). So this is also filling your screen. Now inside that you have a text view with width and height set to fill it's parent (LinearLayout), and since LinearLayout is taking full screen, your TextView will fill the whole screen.

The best way to support smaller screen is that in your res directory create a layout-small folder and place the same xml layout file in there but change the dimensions of your textView.  If you want the text to be as large as its size, you can do "wrap_content" for both width and height. You can also specify android:textSize in dp to play around with different font sizes.

Comment: You made me a bit confused 777! :) I'll make it in a bit

Comment: Sorry about that. What are you confused about? Basically you in your layout have a Relative Layout as the outermost view and you tell it to fill screen then you tell your LinearLayout to match its parent so it also fills screen and then you tell TextView to also fill to its parent so your TextView appears on full screen.

Comment: What you want to do is have a layout-small folder inside your res folder and place that same xml in there, which android will automatically load when it sees your on a smaller display. In that xml just set your width and height of textView to wrap_content and have a smaller font size if that's what you want on a smaller screen.

Comment: I recommend you read the developer guide on supporting multiple screens. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#1d72c3"
        tools:context=".main" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/abus"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="text"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```